# Automatically run executable files with third party program/script in Windows

Tags: windows, batch, script, windows-registry

It is possible to launch an exe file using a third party program through the context menu.

My problem is that an exe file might be triggered by a script or by another application on which I don't have control.

**How can I force every executable files to run using a third party program/script ?**

`Comodo Programs Manager` has a running service that automatically monitor any installation of exe file. How do they proceed ? Is it possible to listen to specific events ?

I thought I could use a **BATCH** script by :

- replacing the default registry key of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command` by something like `path\to\my\script.bat "%1 %*"`
- in the script, do custom stuff like logging and then call the executable :

  ```
  ...

  echo %DATE% %TIME% %* >> "somewhere\logging.txt"

  ...

  :2
  @REM Monitor file (same as context menu open with ...)
  path/to/monitoring.exe %*
  goto end

  ...
  ```

This would work for a PDF file for example. But it obviously doesn't work for executables because `path/to/monitoring.exe %*`, when executed, is running the script again ... and I can't find a way to launch an executable without going through the registry file association.

Is it something possible ?

Comment: Have you tried using Windows OS in-built "Task Scheduler" to run an exe on an event?. From Start menu > type "Task Scheduler" > Create Task > name the task > Triggers tab > choose when it has to trigger from "Begin the Task" list box > choose the time frame > Ok > Now, Action tab > New > Start a Program > provide the path. Check this and the results.

Comment: It might be easier to just monitor tasks and immediately kill the ones you want to block

Comment: How do I trigger the task when an exe file is opened ? Which event should I listen to ?

Comment: For those interested about how to trigger task when an exe file is opened : http://superuser.com/questions/843645/how-to-trigger-a-task-each-time-an-executable-file-is-open-with-windows-task-sch/843767#843767